# Mirror Entries; Benefits vs Issues

Tags: regression, forecasting, boosting

I am working on a binary predictive model using logistic regression and XGBoost and had a dataset with mirrored training sets. For example take these two dataframes

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 1 ], [1, 3, 0 ], [4, 6, 1 ]], columns=['Diff_Average_Running Time', 'Diff_Average_Max_Speed', 'Result'])

df_2 = pd.DataFrame([[-1, -2, 0 ], [-1, -3, 1 ], [-4, -6, 0 ]], columns=['Diff_Average_Running Time', 'Diff_Average_Max_Speed', 'Result'])
```

where 1 indicates a win, and 0 indicates a loss. I wanted to ask what are some of the benefits of including mirrored data sets versus the cons? One of my first concerns was that the model would overfit, and that the model complexity would be increased. Is there any pros to keeping these mirrored outputs?